# Change data frame with factors to a big matrix R

Tags: r, factors

I have a big data frame (22k rows, 400 columns) which is generated using read.csv from a csv file. It appears that every column is a factor and all the row values are the levels of this factor.

I now want to do some analysis (like PCA) but I can't work with it unless it is a matrix, but even when I try it like matrix, all I get is

```
> prcomp(as.matrix(my_data))
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Is there a way of transforming this data frame with factors to a simple big matrix?

I am new in R so forgive all the (maybe terrible) mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: More info on factors: http://blog.haunschmid.name/how-to-handle-factors-in-r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it that way:

```
df<-data.frame(a=as.factor(c(1,2,3)), b=as.factor(c(2,3,4)))
m<-apply(apply(df, 1, as.character), 1, as.numeric)
```

**apply** uses a method on the given data.frame. It is important not to leave out to transform it to character first, because otherwise it will be converted to the internal numeric representation of the factor.

To add column names, do this:

```
m<-m[-1,] # removes the first 'empty' row
colnames(m)<-c("a", "b") # replace the right hand side with your desired column names, e.g. the first row of your data.frame
```

One more tip. You probably read the data.frame from a file, when you set the parameter header=TRUE, the first row will not be the header but the column names of the data.frame will be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much Verena, it worked! I have now another problem though. As in the first row of the data frame are the labels, I got NAs. I tried to add again the labels with  > m[1,]=as.character(my_data[1,]), but all I get is some numbers in the place of the names. It seems that R still treats the first row of my data not as character but factor(?). Interestingly, it worked with the labels of the rows that I had in the first column, so when I tried that >m[,1]=as.vector(my_data[,1]) the labels were placed perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the first row of your data frame is the header (like column names) ? A matrix can not have character / string values.

Comment: Added an answer @Vagos